# Problem with WF4 Poco persisting

Tags: persistence, workflow-foundation, poco

I have a workflow and am persisting it into the database. It all worked fine until I tried using entities in the workflow. Because I'm using POCOs the workflow seems to have trouble serializing the object, especially the relationships.

Now the weird thing is, the first time I start the workflow the serialization works and the object is realoaded into the workflow on resuming the bookmark. But this time when persisting the workflow, I get the following exception:
"The EntityCollection object could not be serialized. This type of object cannot be serialized when the RelationshipManager belongs to an entity object that does not implement IEntityWithRelationships."

I saw that this might help, but I don't have a service and haven't figured out how to get it working without one.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705457.aspx

Does anyone have suggestions? Or do you think switching to use services would solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: What are these objects?  Often WF uses objects which are actually domain objects, not objects that "belong" to the WF.  I always want my domain objects available, and not persisted and or duplicated in a WF.  So all my object persistence is by conventional ORM.  The WF only keeps Ids.  When the WF activates it retrieves any objects it needs, then releases them all when done.  WF should not persist Domain objects anyway , only persist its's owned objects i.e ones that only have scope in the WF.  If your POCOs actually belong to the WF, not sure what is best, I've never needed that myself.

Comment: @Sisyphus Thanks, I decided to to it this way and only save the IDs. I need the values of a user in the workflow. Is there any way I can load the user only once and using it in all activities, without it being persisted?

Comment: You can add a member and mark it NonSerialized.  That way it is available for all activities to use.  When and where and how you choose to instantiate any members that are not persisted will depend on your specifics.  The only rule is the obvious one - you are responsible for explicitly instantiating any members that were not persisted before they are accessed.  If you use member variables instead instantiating objects at the point of use make sure you are aware of all the points where your workflows can idle then rehydrate, don't overlook any delays etc.

Comment: I would have to do that on the POCO, right? Or can I set this only for the workflow? Because the same model is used for multiple projects and normally the members have to be serializable.

Comment: You can use the NonSerialized attribute tag only in the workflow when you declare the module level variables so all activities in the workflow have access to the objects without the persistence engine trying to serialize them.  It does not affect the class itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should be able to figure it out now =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects stored as variables in Workflow are serialized and deserialized when saved to persistence.
There is no opportunity for you to get involved in this serialization process as there is with a WCF service.
Your options would be to use types that dont come from your Entity Framework POCO library or move the code to a service that you call from WF.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was searching for. I took up Sisyphus way of doing it and am only persisting the ID.